# Query result and display on a webpage (Nested Array)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, twig

```
    {% for i in coupontesting %}
    <center>

        <div class="rectangle">
    <span class="right">Store Link</span><span class="left">{{ i.seller_store_name   }}</span>
    <div class="coupon-frame">
                        <div class="coupon-left-div coupon-align-center">
                            <div style="padding: 1.125rem;border-left: 1px solid #d4d4d4;">
                                <div style="position:relative;">
                                    <div class="coupon-left-img-div text-center coupon-align-center orange pt-32">
                    <span class="bold-18">{{ i.name }}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="coupon-ticket-frame">
                                <div class="coupon-ticket-frame-style">
                                    <div class="oupon-ticket-frame-line"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="coupon-right-div coupon-align-center">
                {{ i.coupon_code }}
                        </div>

            <div class="coupon-right-div coupon-align-center">
                <button> Use Now </button>
            </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    </div>
    </center>
{% endfor %}
```

Above is the view page

Below is my query from Model Page

```
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM coupon c INNER JOIN coupon_customer cc ON c.coupon_id = cc.coupon_id LEFT JOIN coupon_store cs ON c.coupon_id = cs.seller_store_id LEFT JOIN seller_store ss ON c.seller_store_id = ss.seller_store_id WHERE cc.customer_id = $customer_id AND c.date_end > NOW() ");

       if ($query->num_rows) {
            return $query->rows;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
```

Table Structure

```
Table: coupon
 coupon_id(PK)   name   coupon_code  date_start   date_end  



Table: coupon_customer 
coupon_id(FK)    customer_id(FK)



Table: coupon_store
 coupon_store_id(PK)    coupon_id(FK)    seller_store_id(FK)



Table: seller_store
 seller_store_id(PK)    seller_store_name    seller_id(FK)

 Table: seller
 seller_id(FK)     seller_name   seller_email

 Table: customer
 customer_id(PK)    customer_name customer_email
```

Everything works fine , but i wanted to ask is there anyway to "grouping the same seller store together ?
Image : https://prnt.sc/rnjbbf (Result from my code)

What i wanted: https://prnt.sc/rnjbqs

If same store then it would group together instead of new line showing the store name again

Comment: Reformat the query result to a nested array that would have a collection of coupons under a single store name and pass that to view.

Comment: do you have any idea how to reformat it ? have some problem on it

Comment: I can't help you if I don't know the exact structure. Can you add that to the question along with your attempt at reformatting?

Comment: @El_Vanja , i have added the table structure on my question

Comment: What are the common properties of sellers you need to group on? Are `'seller_store_name'`s tied to only one `'seller_store_id'`? What about `'seller_id'`? Are you going to use all these things in the template? Right now I'm doing a lot of guessing.

Comment: @El_Vanja , yes 'seller_store_name' tied to only one 'seller_store_id' , for 'seller_id' is the seller ID (which linked to different table) , i have updated on the question with PK and FK , sorry for the trouble

Comment: @El_Vanja , the things that i needed to group on are  `seller_store_id` , which show in the image (here: https://prnt.sc/rnjbqs)  , where if the same store it will show the 2nd coupon code instead of the whole "thing"(which list out store name and store link again)

Comment: Is there anything else that changes the data before it's passed into the template? That `$this->db->query` line looks like Codeigniter. I ask because you use `{{ i.seller_store }}` in the template and there is no field in the database called only `seller_store`.

Comment: @El_Vanja , my bad it was supposed to be `seller_store_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a query result set like this (I removed most of the fields for brevity):

```php
$rows = [
    ['seller_store_id' => 1, 'seller_store_name' => 'Foodlama', 'seller_id' => 11, 'coupon_id' => 6322],
    ['seller_store_id' => 2, 'seller_store_name' => 'BlueFood Market', 'seller_id' => 33, 'coupon_id' => 555],
    ['seller_store_id' => 2, 'seller_store_name' => 'BlueFood Market', 'seller_id' => 33, 'coupon_id' => 7787],
];
```

You can then reformat that result set to be grouped by the store:

```php
$reformatted = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // here we get all the other key => value pairs that aren't used for grouping
    $nonStoreInfo = array_filter($row, function ($key) {
        return $key !== 'seller_store_id' && $key !== 'seller_store_name' && $key !== 'seller_id';
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
    /*
     * We have to manually add any data that is common for the group.
     *
     * Here we overwrite it with each iteration to avoid unnecessary conditional statements
     * (checking if the key exists and has a value). It's cleaner and more concise like this.
     * It doesn't matter because it is the same for every group anyway.
    */
    $reformatted[$row['seller_store_id']]['seller_store_name'] = $row['seller_store_name'];
    $reformatted[$row['seller_store_id']]['seller_id'] = $row['seller_id'];
    $reformatted[$row['seller_store_id']]['coupons'][] = $nonStoreInfo;
}
```

Note that I made a guess about `seller_id`. If it can be different for any `seller_store_id`, then you have to remove it from the `array_filter` callback and also remove the manual assignment `$reformatted[$row['seller_store_id']]['seller_id'] = $row['seller_id'];`. Likewise, if you need to *add* something to the group, you'd have to add the key comparison in `array_filter` and add the manual assignment.

This will ultimately output an array like this:

```php
Array (
    [1] => Array (
        [seller_store_name] => Foodlama
        [seller_id] => 11
        [coupons] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [coupon_id] => 6322
            )
        )
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [seller_store_name] => BlueFood Market
        [seller_id] => 33
        [coupons] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [coupon_id] => 555
            )
            [1] => Array (
                [coupon_id] => 7787
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Now in your template you can iterate the top level (stores) and then iterate the coupons within the stores. You can play around with the array structure and the exact data you need in the group to fit your needs.

Comment: Hi , thanks for the explaination , by looking at the array , ya this is the style that i needed.  m but due to my limitation on my knowledge for the programming skill , i would like to ask a dumb question is that for the $reformatted and the foreach , where should i put ?

Comment: Inside `if ($query->num_rows)`. And then return `$reformatted` instead of the original result set.